# How to split or get the value in column and update in another column in same table? php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to ask how to get the value of the column and update into another column with same id..
this data came from email piping and i want to separate the value of the body and update into the expense , net and gross field..

i don`t know how to do it.. i hope you can help me guys.. thank you

here is my table

```
+------+---------+--------------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| id   | subject | body               | expense |   net    | gross | email    |
+------+---------+--------------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
|  1   | Sales   | Expense = 2000     |    0    |    0     |   0   | ex@ex.com|
|      |         | netIncome = 5000   |         |          |       |          | 
|      |         | Gross    = 10000   |         |          |       |          |
+------+---------+--------------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET expense = LEFT(body, LOCATE("netIncome",body))
```

Comment: i try your code.. but it give the result of N... only the first letter. and try to get the Gross the result ( Net Income = 10000 
Expense = 2000 
G )  . i want to get the number instead of the word.. i hope you help me with this...thank you